# Oxygen tolerant RAFT polymerization using AIBN?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, redox, polymers, organic-oxidation

I want to do some RAFT polymerizations but don't have a nitrogen line at the moment. It seems that people have recently implemented oxygen scavenging strategies to enable open-air RAFT polymerization. In Ref. 1-4 and many similar references, people have used ascorbic acid or trithiocarbonate/blue light as the scavenger and transfer the scavenged electrons to photocatalysts to act as the initiator for  polymerization. My question is, can I add ascorbic acid + copper or ferrous iron to a reaction mixture to serve as oxygen scavengers and separately just use AIBN as a radical initiator instead of the photocatalysts?

(1)  Zhang, T.; Yeow J.; Boyer, C. A cocktail of vitamins for aqueous RAFT polymerization in an open-to-air microtiter plate. *Polym. Chem.* **2019**, *10*, 4643-4654. [DOI 10.1039/C9PY00898E](https://doi.org/10.1039/C9PY00898E).

(2)  Yeow, J.; Chapman, R.; Xu, J.; Boyer, C. Oxygen tolerant photopolymerization for ultralow volumes. *Polym. Chem.* **2017**, *8*, 5012-5022. [DOI 10.1039/C7PY00007C](https://doi.org/10.1039/C7PY00007C)

(3) Shanmugam, S.; Xu, J.; Boyer, C. Aqueous RAFT Photopolymerization with Oxygen Tolerance. *Macromolecules* **2016**, *49*, 9345-9357. [DOI 10.1021/acs.macromol.6b02060](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.macromol.6b02060)

(4)  Fu, Q.; Xie, K.; McKenzie, T. G.; Qiao, G. G. Trithiocarbonates as intrinsic photoredox catalysts and RAFT agents for oxygen tolerant controlled radical polymerization. *Polym. Chem.* **2017**, *8*, 1519-1526. [DOI 10.1039/C6PY01994C](https://doi.org/10.1039/C6PY01994C)